print function info without repeating or explicit calling a function in ruby
For debugging propose, in each method there is a print of the function namespace and its argument
module Test
  def self.foo(arg1, arg2)
    args = method(__method__).parameters.to_h { |p| [p.last, binding.local_variable_get(p.last.to_s)] }
    puts "#{Module.nesting.first}.#{__method__}: #{args}"
  end

  def self.bar(arg1, arg2)
    args = method(__method__).parameters.to_h { |p| [p.last, binding.local_variable_get(p.last.to_s)] }
    puts "#{Module.nesting.first}.#{__method__}: #{args}"
  end
end

Rather than repeating the first 2 lines in each function:

To support single point of modification, how can they be extracted to a function (e.g. function named print_function_info()) which can be invoked by any given function (e.g. from foo() and bar())?
Rather than explicit calling print_function_info() from every other function, is there a way to tell ruby to call print_function_info() when any function is executed?


Have a look at TracePoint

@Stefan Thanks. It looks promising but I couldn't get TracePoint.new(:call) to be called only on when my functions are called (the TracePoint is invoked for every function call). Any idea how it should be properly done?

@Stefan I think I found how to do it. Thank you for the lead.

You might want to post your solution as an answer then.

This might do the trick.
Would love to hear about a better way.
module MethodTracer
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
    base.singleton_class.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  def self.append_features(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
    base.singleton_class.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def method_added(method_name)
      unless method_name == :method_added || method_name == :singleton_method_added
        module_name = self.name || 'anonymous'
        MethodTracer.trace_method_calls(module_name, method_name)
      end
    end

    def singleton_method_added(method_name)
      unless method_name == :method_added || method_name == :singleton_method_added
        module_name = self.name || 'anonymous'
        MethodTracer.trace_method_calls(module_name, method_name)
      end
    end
  end

  def self.trace_methods(module_name)
    module_name.singleton_methods(false).each do |method_name|
      trace_method_calls(module_name, method_name)
    end
  end

  def self.trace_method_calls(module_name, method_name)
    TracePoint.new(:call) do |tp|
      if tp.self.to_s == module_name.to_s && tp.method_id.to_sym == method_name.to_sym
        args = tp.binding.local_variables.map { |var| [var, tp.binding.local_variable_get(var)] }.to_h
        puts "#{tp.self.to_s}.#{method_name}(): #{args}"
      end
    end.enable
  end
end

module Test
  include MethodTracer

  def self.foo(arg1, arg2)
  end

  def self.bar(arg1, arg2)
  end
end


I feel like this answer would benefit from more elaboration on what you've done and how it addresses the question. "Try this: " answers are generally not good ones.

Thank you. You are more than welcome to offer a concrete edit/changes.
